# How to make a Winforms application with remote sql

Tags: winforms, sql-server-2005, web-services

I have written a simple program(Winforms.NET), that selects a random word from a dictionary (DB table) everyday. When the DB is embedded its fine, but if I want to make the program take the data from a remote server.

I suppose I have to put the ip address of SQL Server host into my connection string, but if host allows remote connections.

Or I will make a WebService that sends the data and my desktop app will consume the WebService. Would it be a right approach.

If yes, any leads on how to consume webservice from WinformsApp.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If using winforms and the server accepts remote connections, then indeed you just need to put the SQL Server instance name or IP address in the connection string. Using a web service has the advantage that allows your data to be accessed from other environments that do not support direct database connections, such as a Silverlight application; but if you are just using winforms, I would rather stick to direct database connections to keep things simple.

Comment: And change the default port, or you will be spammed with failed 'sa' accesses.

Answer (score 0):

A webservice is a better approach for a number of reasons - because it better protects your database and because its more likely to work well given that http (as a protocol) is more likely to be accessible from you client.

Web services (or better WCF services) are straightforward to create and consume from a Win Forms app if you're developing with Visual Studio and have control over both ends.

First create your service application - details depend on what you want to do, then from within your forms application you add a service reference (although again it depends on which tools you're using).